# Java: Using type punning on primitive arrays?

Tags: java, buffer, primitive-types, bytebuffer, type-punning

I need to be able to convert byte arrays to/from other primitive type arrays, but instead of casting, I need [**type punning**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning). *Correct term for raw copy without casting?*

I thought it would be possible to do the following:

```
// idea: byte[12] -> int[3], and int[3] -> byte[12]

int[] ints;

ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(
    new byte[]{ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3 });
IntBuffer ib = bb.asIntBuffer();

ints = ib.array(); // java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
ints = ib.duplicate().array(); // java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Unfortunately, it seems that `bb.asIntBuffer()` is **not** creating a new IntBuffer by copying the content "bitwise" or "raw", but creates a new "view" on existing ByteBuffer. That's why `.array()` is intended to fail.

I browsed around in JDK's sources, and found few classes, which are used by all these buffer classes and **would** do the stuff I need, but are internal (such as the class `Unsafe`).

While I think that my goal could be achieved by wrapping the byte buffer in some `ObjectInputStream` and read the primitive values by `.readInt()`, I think it would be a messy and slow workaround.

So, are there any other solutions possible **without** doing magical primitive type arithmetics (shifting, checking endians, ...)?

*NOTE: I need both directions: byte[12] -> int[3], and int[3] -> byte[12]*

Comment: Note that if you do the bit shifting yourself you don't have to worry about endianness. Java is always big endian.

Comment: I think the whole point of "type punning" is that precisely there's *NO* conversion going on (besides the type conversion itself, but this is *not* modifying the data underneath).  I remember lots of C and Assembly fun doing things like that 20 years ago.  So I'd say "type punning" is definitely *not* the right term if you explicitely convert your arrays, for the whole point of "type punning" is to do hacky magic *without* the cost of conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the javadoc, array() [1] returns the buffer's backing array which is the array you specify with the call to wrap() [2].

Hence, you must create a new array with the desired type. But the arithmetics can still be handled via the Buffer classes.

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[]{ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3 });
IntBuffer ib = bb.asIntBuffer();

int[] intArray = new int[ib.limit()];
ib.get(intArray);
```

Backwards requires a little bit of calculation by yourself.

```
ByteBuffer newBb = ByteBuffer.allocate(intArray.length*4);
newBb.asIntBuffer().put(intArray);
byte[] byteArray = newBb.array();
```

See:

[1] http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#array%28%29

[2] http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#wrap%28byte[]%29

Comment: Great! Never came to the idea to look at those `get(...)` methods. *Consistent API naming rules ;)*

Comment: Uhm, any idea how to do this backwards (`NBuffer` to `ByteBuffer`)?  

`ByteBuffer` has all there `.asSomething()` methods, but `IntBuffer` does not.

Comment: Very nice! And without loops!

Comment: Note: If you want to get the int-array, modify it and store it again back in the same ByteBuffer, this is also possible. You can reuse the original ByteBuffer+IntBuffer. You just have to go `ib.clear()` first before you call `ib.put(intArray)`. It is like a file-stream object which is designed to be read/written once (unless you call `.clear()` to reset it). The IntBuffer is a "view" which points at the original byte-array but has new mark+position+limit+capacity values. So after updating `ib`, you can call `bb.array()` to get the bytes as a byte array (`ib.array()` returns an int array).

Answer (score 1):

*Many thanks to **wierob** for his code for converting byte[]->int[] !*

I played around a bit to get the opposite direction working.

## 1) API

```
// byte[] -> int[]
public static int[] punnedToInteger(byte[] in){
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(in);
    IntBuffer pb = bb.asIntBuffer();

    int[] out = new int[pb.limit()];
    pb.get(out);

    return out;
}

// int[] -> byte[]
public static byte[] punnedFromInteger(int[] in){
    byte[] out = new byte[in.length * Integer.SIZE / Byte.SIZE];
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(out);

    for(int i=0; i<in.length; ++i){
        bb.putInt(in[i]);
    }

    return out;
}
```

## 2) Test case

```
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[]{ 0,0,0,1, 0,0,1,0, 0,1,0,0, 1,0,0,0 };
    int[] ints = punnedToInteger(bytes);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));
    System.out.println();
}
{
    int[] ints = new int[]{ 1, 256, 65536, 16777216 };
    byte[] bytes = punnedFromInteger(ints);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
    System.out.println();
}
```

## 3) Output

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 256, 65536, 16777216]

[1, 256, 65536, 16777216]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: please note that int -> byte could be a lossy conversion

Comment: Well, I understand that `int -> byte` **cast** is lossy. But why **type punning** could be lossy?